# Verified and CodeRview label missing in the gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

I am building e gerrit.

But after upload the code, I can see the commit in webpage but could not found the verify button.
I have add the Label verified in the project.config.
The Verify button dose not show.
After i grant the permission by

> On the Access tab, choose Edit. Under refs/heads/*, add a "Label Verified" permission and assign a suitable group.

The CodeRview button is disappear too.

Answer (score 0):

Either you are not logged-in to Gerrit, you don't have permissions to Code-Review / Verify, or you don't have access to this branch.

Make sure you are logged-in as a Gerrit Administrator, and check the access-rights.